# How to connect UIScrollView to IBOutlet

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I have an iPad app using Storyboards.  I have a UIView that I have split into 2 areas; let's call them "top" (contains a UIView) and "bottom" (contains a UIScrollVIew, with a UIView sub-view).  In both cases I draw on the UIViews; the difference is the UIView which is a subv iew has to be scrolled.

My question is how do I connect the UIScrollView to an IBOutlet so I can set the ContentSize?  And where do I place the IBOutlet definition, in AppDelegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not place the outlet in the Application Delegate. Your app should contain a root view controller (created automatically if you're using a single view application template), which should handle anything related to the application's initial view. Once you have one, open the storyboard in the editor. Open an assistant editor using the buttons along the top, and use the drop-down menu at the top of the assistant editor to open up the header file of the controller. Select the scroll view, and control-drag from it into the controller's interface. Xcode will prompt you to make an outlet, allowing you to change the name. Let's use `scrollView` for the name. Select `weak` for the memory management, since it's already being retained by its superview. Xcode should automatically synthesize accessors, and now you can access the property using `self.scrollView` from within the controller's instance methods. Alternatively, you can select the scroll view and set its tag in the attributes inspector to any unique number, like 4. Then, you can use `[self.view viewWithTag:4]` to get a reference to it.

Comment: Metabble: This is an iPad app, using Storyboards and a UITabBarController, currently with two (2) scenes; there is NO "root view controller" that I see.  What I do have is a "Tab Bar Controller", but that is not where the UIScrollView is... it's on one of the other scenes.

So, how do I modify your instructions to handle this situation?

Comment: I found this [link (http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/uiscrollview-examples/) and it's all now connected... haven't tried to test it yet, but at least I got everything connected and it's a clean build.  Thank you for your time; I appreciate it.

Comment: @spokane-dude For further reference, whatever controller handles what initially appears is generally your root VC. In this case, I made the assumption that your root VC managed the scroll view, but whatever view controller manages the scene is where it should go. If you are unsure, select the scene, click "View Controller" at the bottom, and go to the Identity Inspector on the right. Whatever it says the "Custom Class" is, is its view controller. It's instantiated and given the views contained in the scene as subviews of its main view.

Comment: Oh, and also, I'm glad to be of assistance. :)

Answer (score 1):

open the storyboard, open the assistant editor. drag (right click drag) from scrollview in IB to header and when asked make the connection

Comment: Oh boy, cant believe I missed it. Thanks a bunch mate @Daij-Djan.